# Identify foreign key relationships without contstraints

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

We have a legacy SQLServer database with few specified foreign key constraints, even though there are many foreign keys. Is there some way to use the server logs to identify the unspecified foreign keys?

Comment: If there are no constraints defined and it was assumed that a column is referencing a column in another table (imaginary Foreign keys) I'm afraid you are out of luck my friend.

Answer (score 0):

If a foreign key constraint isn't specified then all you have is a collection of tables, the server logs won't tell you anything.

All you will be able to do is get some clues from the database, for example the foreign keys may be fairly obvious i.e. PartID on a OrderDetails table. You might be able to examine views, stored procedures and other server code to find JOINs though not all of these will indicate a FK. If the system is live and active then you can also took at the queries run against the database for the same joins.

Once you've identified some potential FKs you can see if the values all match up using a full outer join like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_1 AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_2 AS t2
ON t1.CandidateID = t2.CandidateID
WHERE t1.CandidateID IS NULL OR t2.t1.CandidateID IS NULL
```

If the tables have data and this this doesn't return any rows then you are likely to have an FK, if it returns a few then you might still have one with a few missed deletes etc.

Comment: That is basically what we are doing, analyzing the queries and looking for obvious ones. I was just hoping that there was some kind of tool that would identify them automatically. It's certainly a solvable problem, but it doesn't look like there is currently a tool that does it cleanly.

Comment: You might want to look at my http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29023514/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-columns-referenced-in-a-stored-procedure/30002523#30002523 and see if you can find joins instead of columns in the cached xml query plans.